# Importance of Bit-manipulation code?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have been programming for the past 3 years and haven't really put in efforts to write bit manipulation code. Having worked on enterprise software, I haven't seen other developers write it either.

Is it a good practice to write a bit manipulation code instead of using the mathematical operations for performing calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More or less, if you're not working with the kind of software that would benefit from bit manipulation, then you probably don't need to be using them.  In fact, in many places they can make code harder to read, and really shouldn't be used unless there is a reason to.

However, if you're interested, they are a useful tool given the right application.  For example, if you have code which is multiplying by a power of two, it can be quicker to just left shift the bits.  This can become important if you determine that the multiplication code is a bottleneck to performance.

One important fact to realize is that some compilers will do some of these forms of optimization (e.g. turning the line `i = i * 2` into a left shift) for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly bizzarre question! No, enterprise code is probably never likely to do bit manipulation. It's usually written in Java/.NET etc and is concerned with pushing messages around and communicating between various systems at a high level.

If however you are writing drivers using C or C++ or assembler, or doing clever low level maths then bit manipulation is probably more important and useful to you. No doubt you will know when to use it if/when the time comes!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the situation. For example right shift and left shift operations are generally faster than the dividing operator. If you need optimization and bit operations are faster than the other approach, you should use bit operations. But don't optimize prematurely. because that's not a good thing to do. If you are sure you need optimization and using bit operators are faster than the previous approach then yes, you should use them.

Comment: But compilers will generally do it for you.

Comment: Bad as a general advice. Compilers usually know better division/multiplication tricks, including of the sort where a single shift doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: No. Use math operators for math operations.